# Oracle Trigger Autonomous Transaction Missing Rows

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two tables: delivery_records and delivery_summary. I've simplified the tables to demonstrate

```
select *
from delivery_records

FILTERLIST   PRICE_DATE   PRICE_VALUE
-------------------------------------
FL_1         1/1/2015     1
FL_1         1/1/2015     2
FL_1         1/1/2015     3
FL_2         1/1/2015     8
FL_2         1/1/2015     9
```

I have a trigger after insert or update for each row on delivery_records which fires the procedure summarize_records so that the delivery_summary table is immediately updated after each modification of the delivery_records table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SNAPSHOT_TRIG
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON DELIVERY_RECORDS FOR EACH ROW

Declare

    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line('Starting trigger');

    SUMMARIZE_RECORDS(:new.filterlist, trunc(sysdate));

    COMMIT;

    dbms_output.put_line('Trigger ended');


EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('SQL Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100));


END DELIV_SNAPSHOT_UPDATE;
```

A filterlist is a group of related delivery records. The summarize_records stored procedure summarizes the delivery counts for each filterlist on each date by running a select on the delivery_records table and then inserting the results into the delivery_summary table which I'd expect to result in the following:

```
select * from delivery_summary

FILTERLIST DATE       DELIVERY_COUNT
------------------------------------
FL_1       1/1/2015   3
FL_2       1/1/2015   2
```

This is working as expected, but it appears the trigger is missing the last record inserted for each filterlist. Almost as if the trigger didn't fire. I've done some researching and someone hinted that the autonomous transaction couldn't see the record of the current transaction. This is the table I'm seeing unless I run some sort of do-nothing update to cause the trigger to fire again.

```
select * from delivery_summary

FILTERLIST DATE       DELIVERY_COUNT
------------------------------------
FL_1       1/1/2015   2
FL_2       1/1/2015   1
```

It was my understanding that as an "after" trigger, the row should be visible for my summary procedure. I had to set the procedure as pragma autonomous since I'm selecting on the table which is being triggered on. I know this is taboo, but it seems like the only way to meet the requirements of a real-time summary table.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? It seemed like this was the perfect use case for a trigger.

Comment: It might be easier to use a view than to try to maintain the summary state with a trigger.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use a view, or potentially a materialized view. Depends on how often the delivery_records table is updated vs how often the delivery_summary table is viewed.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a lot of peripheral functionality that I left out so that it wouldn't be a ridiculously long question. Between the volume of delivery records and the number of columns to report and summarize on a view just wouldn't provide the needed performance. And certain columns are frozen (not updated) for historical dates to provide an audit log. A view couldn't provide this.

Comment: @AndyIngraham - a materialised view might, but yes, it depends what the `summarize_records` is doing. A trigger has its own performance penalty, of course, especially if you end up with multiple inserts trying to update the same summary. Anyway, no, the data you've inserted isn't visible to an autonomous transaction even in an after trigger - that's what makes it autonomous, as it's outside the current (uncommitted) transaction.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario I think using `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` annotation is wrong because:

> In one transaction you are updating `delivery_records` and
>   you are marking that transaction as separated (by using pragma
>   AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION) from which you are reading data from
>   `delivery_records`, in.

So I prefer don't use AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION and bring the codes of procedure inside the trigger and at there directly calculate required values and insert it into `delivery_summary`

Comment: Unfortunately I need to grab other records from the delivery_records tables that are related to the current record being inserted or updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a statement trigger, i.e. skip the `FOR EACH ROW`.

In your trigger you have to do it like this (considering only the updates):

```
UPDATE delivery_summary
SET (FILTERLIST, DATE, DELIVERY_COUNT) = 
    (SELECT FILTERLIST, DATE, COUNT(*) 
    FROM delivery_records
    GROUP BY FILTERLIST, DATE);
```

However, the better solution would be to put all this into a stored procedure and call this procedure instead of using a trigger.

Comment: I'm calling a stored procedure which does something very similar (though quite a bit more complicated) to the above code. The problem I'm facing is the count(*) is returning expected_count - 1. It's like the current records doesn't exist to the count(*)

Comment: Do you use again some `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`?

Comment: No I have autonomous_transaction declared in the trigger but not the procedure. Do I have the autonomous_transaction declaration in the wrong place?

Comment: Maybe my recommondation was not clear: Remove **all** triggers and do everything by a procedure.